# Why does property gets nulled from view to code page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have something like this (reduced for brevity)

Expenditures.cshtml.cs:

```
    public class Expenditures: PageModel {
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)] public string PersonnelNo {get;set;}
        
        public async Task OnGetAsync() { //some code 
        }

        public async Task < IActionResult > OnPostAsync() {
            return Page();
          }
    }
```

and Expenditures.cshtml

```
@page
@using DataAccessLibrary.Models
@model WorkInProgress.Pages.Expenditures
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Expenditures";
}
<h1>Project Information</h1>
<form method="post">
   <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead class = "table-light">
         <tr>
            <th>@Model.PersonnelNo</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
   </table>
   <div class="form-control">
      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PersonnelNo, Model.PersonnelNo)
      <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
   </div>
</form>
```

this works the first time, when the page loads (PersonnelNo in the .cs file has a value)

however when I press the submit button and I try to reload the same page, the value for PersonnelNo is nulled.

Is there a way to pass the parameter from the view back to the .cs file so it can be reused?

I thought the `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PersonnelNo, Model.PersonnelNo)` should do this, but is not working

Comment: Remove the `, Model.PersonnelNo`?

Comment: @GSerg no, changing it to @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PersonnelNo) still nulls the value

Comment: In the view, what you do you want to do about the parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below demo I can get the value, you can refer to it.

**First way**

Adding parameter to the handler method.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]       
        public string PersonnelNo { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            PersonnelNo = "1";
        }
    
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string PersonnelNo)
        {
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<h1>Project Information</h1>
<form method="post">
   <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead class = "table-light">
         <tr>
            <th>@Model.PersonnelNo</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
   </table>
   <div class="form-control">
      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PersonnelNo, Model.PersonnelNo)
      <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
   </div>
</form>
```

Result:

[image]

**Second way**

Add name attribute to do model binding

Add this line`<input name="PersonnelNo" type="hidden" />` after  `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PersonnelNo, Model.PersonnelNo)`

Result:

[image]

Comment: I understand the logic of what you're posting, sadly is not working for me right now, I'm having problem when the page reloads with an asp-route and when it does post. it seems my complete code has bugs.

Comment: Can you show me your code and error message ? @Baldie47

Comment: I have created a gist: https://gist.github.com/gasguirre/3438736a230216a8868db6a840a378f1

and a small explanation of what happens in the comments